# Global variable $_FILE returning size of file as 0 on JSON response to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using Dropzone.js for my website and am getting stuck on sending a response through server side.
This is my code.
**upload.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
$target_dir = '../assets/uploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['filetoupload']['name']);
$imagetype = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file , PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$sizeoffile = $_FILES['filetoupload']['size'];
if( $sizeoffile > 3000000){
    $response = 'File is Too Big. Max 3MB !';
    $status = 417;
    goto respond;
}
else{
    $response = 'checking';
    $status = 200;
    goto respond;
}
respond:
$data = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'responseText' => $response ,
    'size' => $sizeoffile
);
echo json_encode($_FILES);//just for checking
?>
```

**uploader.js**

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropZone',{
    /* ... */
    init: function(){
         this.on("success", function(file, response){
         console.log(file);
         console.log(response);
        });
        } 
 });
```

The JSON response from the server side to javascript on console looks like this.
[Have a look at this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91rdC.png)
Thanks for any help!

While if I choose an image of size less than 2Mb It is working
[This is another image have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmH5H.png)

Comment: What is `error:1` (in the first image, and it's better to not post images as links)  if it's the PHP error `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`  Then you need to increase that and `post_max_size`  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your linked images (better to just post as text)

The first one says `error:1` in PHP this is

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

PHP's common default is maximum 2 MB upload file size

> While if I choose an image of size less than 2Mb It is working

These two things lead me to believe you need to increase the upload size:

```
 upload_max_filesize 
 post_max_size
```

Both of which can be found in the `php.ini` configuration file for PHP.  I usually set this to about `80M` right off the bat, anything much more then that and you should be using something like `FTP` for the uploads.

you may also run into issues with the max execution time limit.  But that is a question for another post.